# Spacing of radio buttons in access 2013

Tags: radio-button, ms-access-2010, radio-group

I am looking for a way to space the radio buttons in a group automatically.  Does anyone know any way.  I know with normal controls, I simply select the group of controls, go to Arrange, Size and Space, Increase or Decrease Horizontal or Equal Horizontal.  I have tried this with Radio buttons in an options group but it does not seem to work.  I would like to have all my buttons equally spaced without having to try to do it manually.  I have many radio groups on my forms and it would take a long time to do this.

I am using Access 2013 but didn't see a tag for it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I guess the easiest thing to do would be to cut the buttons out of the frame (select all, then ctrl+C), then paste them to an empty area of your form (select the last control, then ctrl+V), space them with Make Equal, and then cut and paste them back to the frame. Easiest of all would be to let the wizard take care of the spacing in the first place.

Comment: The Wizard- lines them up vertically, I want them lined up horizontally.  Not sure maybe I am missing a step in the wizard?

Comment: No, you are not missing a step. Put the buttons somewhere on your form via paste, arrange them as you wish and paste back to your option frame. The alternative is a big box of code.

Comment: Thanks- that's what I thought.  Will do, create 1 then copy and just realign with the data control.

Comment: Thank you @Fionnuala - your comment really deserves to be an Answer!